# jquery hover and toggle

Tags: jquery, hover, toggle

I have some text that is hidden that I would like to display when a button is clicked.

The button has four various display states. When the text is not displayed it should be pointing down and when the text is displayed it should point up. In addition there are hover states for the down and up.

I would also like for the button to change to its hover state when a user rolls over the h1 tag. It should also show the correct hover state based on if the text is displayed.

I have a [fiddle link to demonstrate](http://fiddle.jshell.net/MGDTech/6jaCt/).

If you remove the function below it works on click but not for the hover state:

```
    $('body.home .entry-content h1').hover(function() {
    $('#hide-text').css('background-position','-26px 0px');

}, function() {
    $('#hide-text').css('background-position','0px 0px');

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your code a bit to use `collapse` as a class instead of just `hover`.  You need both classes because you want to have two different states (collapsed and not collapsed) each with it's own hover.  Your first attempt failed because you were resetting the `background-position` to the collapsed location on hover, no matter what state you intended.

[DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/6jaCt/7/)

JQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('body.home .entry-content h1').append("<div id='hide-text'></div>");


    $('body.home .entry-content h1').hover(function () {
        $('#hide-text').addClass("hover");

    }, function () {
        $('#hide-text').removeClass("hover");
    });


    $('#hide-text').toggle(function () {
        $(this).addClass('collapse');
        $('body.home .entry-content h2').fadeIn(500);

    }, function () {

        $(this).removeClass('collapse');
        $('body.home .entry-content h2').fadeOut(500);

    });

});
```

CSS

```
body.home .entry-content h2 {
    display: none;
}
#hide-text {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
    height: 22px;
    width: 26px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    background: url('http://www.mgrear.com/clients/gls/wp-content/themes/gravity-lab-studios/images/home-button.png') 0px 0px no-repeat;
}
#hide-text:hover, #hide-text.hover {
    background: url('http://www.mgrear.com/clients/gls/wp-content/themes/gravity-lab-studios/images/home-button.png') -26px 0px no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#hide-text.collapse {
    background: url("http://www.mgrear.com/clients/gls/wp-content/themes/gravity-lab-studios/images/home-button.png") -52px 0px no-repeat;
}
#hide-text.collapse:hover, #hide-text.collapse.hover {
    background: url("http://www.mgrear.com/clients/gls/wp-content/themes/gravity-lab-studios/images/home-button.png") -78px 0px no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. That works! I now understand that I should have just created two classes to handle the two functions. That really helped me.

Comment: I'm new to the stackoverflow community. Is it beneficial for me to answer other member's questions?

Comment: If you are a serious developer, having a SO profile could be good for your career. It's an additional tool for recruiters and employers verify your skills.  It's also a way of separating the loner coders from those that can help the team become better. As for this question, if it's been solved by my answer, just click the check box next to my answer and 'accept' it.

Comment: SO can also increase your skill set in various areas because you are answering problems before you even see them yourself.  Spending a couple hours a week answering questions, is equivalent to continuing education in my book.

Comment: Thanks Michael for the tips. You can definitely learn more by helping others. I'm responding to questions right now. I think I just caught the SO fever!